# ng-grid get column index with row.entity possible?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I am able to access the row.entity object for my drag and drop directives using https://github.com/logicbomb/lvlDragDrop/blob/master/script/lvl-drag-drop.js. I get the row.entity with code like this

```
angular.element(element).scope().$parent.row.entity
```

With this code I can see the row's data, but what I need is the column. Basically I can drag and drop an ng-grid cell into any other ng-grid cell, I want to know all the data the row has, as well as the specific cell that was drag/dropped.

I have tried `$parent.col`, but not sure what else to try.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show column index

cellTemplate: '{{grid.renderContainers.body.visibleColumnCache.indexOf(col)}}'

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the column data from the row entity. It looks like you may be able to do something like 'row.entity[col.index]'. Try inspecting $parent.row.entity to see what else is stored in there.